# How to config where Syntastic is going to generate the .class files?

Tags: java, class, vim, auto-generate, syntastic

I am writing some code to my phd project and I am using VIM as my code editor.
As I am coding in Java, I chose Syntastic to check and compile my code. So far so good.

My issue comes when I try to create a directory with all my .classes. I want to do this, because then I intend to create a .jar using this directory using a simple make file. So, this is my scenario:

**source code:**

C:\Users\LABIMD05\workspace\backhoe-nomvn2\src (all .java)

**class files:**

C:\Users\LABIMD05\workspace\backhoe-nomvn2\bin\classes (where I want to put all the .classes)

In this way, let's say I am coding br.ufrn.Project. When I use :SyntasticCheck, I want the br.ufrn.Project .class file to be generate at:

C:\Users\LABIMD05\workspace\backhoe-nomvn2\bin\classes\br\ufrn\Project.class

and not at:

C:\Users\LABIMD05\workspace\backhoe-nomvn2\src\br\ufrn\Project.class (the same of the .java)

Here goes the options that I am using at my _vimrc file

```
let g:syntastic_java_javac_classpath = 'C:\Users\LABIMD05\workspace\szz_lib\*;C:\Users\LABIMD05\workspace\backhoe-nomvn2\bin\classes'
let g:syntastic_java_javac_delete_output = 0
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'passive',
            \ 'passive_filetypes': ['java']}
```

**THE PROBLEM**:
Everytime I compile br.ufrn.Project file, the .class file goes to the **same directory** of the .java file

I thought it would be because Syntastic would create the .class file in the current working directory. Then I used:

```
cd C:\Users\LABIMD05\workspace\backhoe-nomvn2\bin\classes
```

To see if Syntastic would create the .class in the desired place. But I had no success.

Would you guys have some clue where can I configure it? I just want to separate the .class files from .java files and then use a make file to create a jar with the binaries only. Simple thing.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Just to clarify:
My environment is: Windows 7, Vim 7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't configure Syntastic to compile the java files to a different location. However, you can make a command that uses SyntasticCheck and compiles the java files to a different directory.

Using the `javac -d dir File.java` command you can tell the java compiler where to generate `.class` files.

Using this you can make a vim command, I called it `Javac` but you can choose what to call it. It will call Syntastic check and generate the `.class` files to the other file.

```
function! Javac()
    execute "w"
    execute "SyntasticCheck"
    execute "!javac -d C:\Users\LABIMD05\workspace\backhoe-nomvn2\bin\classes %"
endfunction

command! Javac :call Javac()
```

If the `SyntasticCheck` part is not necessary you can remove that.

Just put this in your `.vimrc` and then you can use `:Javac` to execute it.
Alternatively you could also put it in `~/.vim/ftplugin/java.vim` if you want it to only be active when editing the java filetype.

Comment: Thank you so much @Zach. It solved my problem! 
However, I have another question: after executing the :Javac command, a cmd line window pops up expecting me to hit any button to close. Do you know what can I do to avoid this it? For example, run the Javac command without any additional window expecting me to hit enter or something?

Comment: Nevermind @Zach, I figured it out. I used the following command instead:

execute "**!start** javac -d C:\Users\LABIMD05\workspace\backhoe-nomvn2\bin\classes %"

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!